# Materialize Sidenav Icon Issue

Tags: materialize

I have here my sidenav but it keeps indenting and indenting everytime i put an icon before my link. Please help me..

```
<ul id="mobile-demo" class="side-nav">
    <li>
    <div class="userView">
        <img class="background" src="http://materializecss.com/images/office.jpg">
        <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="http://materializecss.com/images/yuna.jpg"></a>
        <a href="#!name"><span class="white-text name">Nelson Maranan</span></a>
        <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">nmaranan11@gmail.com</span></a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">home</i>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">list</i>Browse</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">message</i>Messages <span class="badge">3</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">notifications</i>Notifications <span class="badge">10</span></a></li>
    <li><div class="divider"></div></li>
    <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
    <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's my screenshot to show the problem:

[image: Image showing the problem I am having]

But when I remove icons it displays just fine. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue too.

Just add this rule in your stylesheet:

```
.side-nav li{
    clear: both;
}
```